# Running Firemonkey android application on another Devices

Tags: android

I developed an application by firemonkey for Android and it work properly on my device. but when I try to run this application on another device the size of and position of component on screen changes.
I want that run my application on all of android devices full screen as same as running on my device
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TGridPanelLayout: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridPanelLayout

You put all your components in the TGridPanelLayout's rows and columns, using RowSpan and ColumnSpan, and change the Align property to Client.